# ListView disappears after return from activity

Tags: android, listview, activity-lifecycle

I have two screens the one which list the records in a listview  **"ListView Screen"** & the second which is used for showing a specific record **"specific record screen"**.
I am using grid_item.xml, which is used to hold the data of a row in the listview.
the grid_item.xml is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/col1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:width="50dip"
        />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/col2"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:width="200dip"
        />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/col3"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:width="200dip"
        />
       <TextView android:id="@+id/col4"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:width="200dip"
        />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/editimage"
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip" 
            android:background="@drawable/edit"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="ClickHandlerForEditImage"
            />  
</LinearLayout>
```

There is an ImageView which is used to open the **"specific record screen"** when its clicked. I have attached the "ClickHandlerForEditImage" event to that imageview (see the last few lines of the above xml).

The code:

```
public void ClickHandlerForEditImage(View v) 
{

    LinearLayout vwParentRow = (LinearLayout)v.getParent();

    TextView txtId = (TextView)vwParentRow.getChildAt(0);

    long rowId =  CommonMethods.GetLong(txtId);

    //Log.d("Inspection", "onItemClick Postion "+ rowId);
    //vwParentRow.refreshDrawableState();      

    if(rowId > 0)
{
       Intent intent = new Intent("com.moftak.db.DatabasesActivity"); 
       intent.putExtra("RecordId", rowId);
       startActivity(intent); 
}

}
```

Now the problem is that it works fine, the **"specific record screen"** is opened, but when i press the "back button", the **"ListView Screen"** is displayed but the ListView (Or the ListView Items) disappears.

Can somebody help me. Thanks in advance for your valuable time & help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a solution... 
Override the onRestart() & add your code here which is populating the list View in my case it is the LoadInspection().

```
@Override 
public void onRestart() 
{ 
     super.onRestart(); 
     LoadInspections(); 
}
```

Can somebody comment on this behavior of List View? Thanks.